# Кавычки в html блоке

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно экранировать/расставить кавычки в коде, чтобы содержимое атрибута data-point стало корректной строкой?

```
<div class="item" data-point="{company:'<div class="_customer-pick__company">Company Name</div>', email:'', link:'<span class="link" onclick="window.open('https://test.org', '_blank'); return true"></span>', phone: '<a href="tel:+79127777777" class="_customer-pick__phone" onclick="yaCounter38297925.reachGoal('header_tel'); return true">+7 (777) 912-77-77</a></div>'}">
  Великий Новгород
</div>
```

Comment: экранировать обратным слэшом **в данном конкретном случае**

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div 
    class="item"
    data-point="{company:'<div class=`_customer-pick__company`>Company Name</div>', email:'', link:'<span class=`link` onclick=`window.open('https://test.org', '_blank'); return true`></span>', phone: '<a href=`tel:+79127777777` class=`_customer-pick__phone` onclick=`yaCounter38297925.reachGoal('header_tel'); return true`>+7 (777) 912-77-77</a></div>'}"
  >
    Великий Новгород
  </div>
```